# How can I split my file into multiple files?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I want to split a file into multiple files. My input is

```
Report : 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
$
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report  
$
Report : 3
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

The output should be:

File 1

```
Report : 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

File 2

```
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
$
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report  
$
```

File 3

```
Report : 3
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

I have tried

```
awk '{print $0 "Report :"> "/tmp/File" NR}' RS="END OF" test.txt
```

but I'm not getting appropriate output.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd add the technology that you want to use on the question title: split file based on content using bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another awk answer:

```
awk '/^Report/{n=$3} {print > "File"n}' input
```

This is similar to nu11p01n73R's answer but uses the third field of each `Report` line to determine the file number.

- When `/^Report/` matches the line, the set `n` to `$3`.
- Use `n` when creating the file name to print each line to

If you have a large number of these blocks, you might need to end up closing files and could use this command instead:

```
awk '/^Report/{f="File"$3; if(lf != f) {close(lf); lf=f}} {print > f}' input
```

- When `/^Report/` matches the line, create a filename `f`.
- If `lf` (last filename) doesn't match `f`, first try to close `lf` then reset `lf`.  Calling close() when `lf` hasn't been set is safe
- print every line to `f`

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like

```
$awk '/^Report/{filename++} {print > "FILE"filename}' input
```

**Test**

```
$awk '/^Report/{filename++} {print > "FILE"filename}' input

$ cat FILE1
Report : 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$

$ cat FILE2
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
$
Report : 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$

$ cat FILE3
Report : 3
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

**What it does**

- `/^Report/` pattern is true for lines that start with `Report` the number in the third colum in the same line is the filename that must be used as the filename for the next couple of lines
- `{filename++}` increments the filename value by one
- `{print > "FILE"filename}` prints each line into the files.

  Eg if `filename` is `1` then this line is same as

  ```
  print > FILE1
  ```

  This is ouput redirection, which is same as the one used in bash etc.

  Note that there is no attribute for `print` if the attribute is missed, then awk prints the entire record. That is it is same as writing `print $0 > "FILE"filename`

Comment: Can you explain me the command. As i am running the same but it's not working for me.

Comment: i don't want filename = $3. it can be anything. I have tried for this but it copy every single line as file.                    awk '/^Report/{print > "tmp/File" NR}' test.txt

Comment: @Viru It does because NR get incremented for each line. so each line will go into each file

Comment: @Viru or if you want the filenames to be incrementing for each record you  can try `awk '/^Report/{filename++} {print > "FILE"filename}' input`

Comment: Can you please give me the solution? i want filename as incremental

Comment: @Viru `awk '/^Report/{filename++} {print > "FILE"filename}' input` will do it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68221/discussion-between-viru-and-nu11p01n73r).

Comment: now the output is splited into two files for Report : 2 ABC DEF GHI JKL $ Report : 2 ABC DEF GHI JKL End of Report $

Comment: @Viru You mean inside one `Report` there can be another `Report` as well

Comment: Means one report has multiple pages. In my case report 2 has multiple page

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
csplit input.txt '/End of Report$/' '{*}'
```

#### Explanation

- [`csplit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) is a UNIX utility that is used to split a file into two or more smaller files determined by context lines.
- `input.txt` This is the file which will be get splitted.
- `'/End of Report$/'` specific pattern like "End of Report" .
- `'{*}'` option which indicates the whole file.

Comment: This seems to be close but not exactly right. It puts the `End of Report` lines into the wrong files. Matching on the `Report` lines instead helps somewhat (but gets you a blank first split file) and doesn't keep records with the same number together.