# How can I split my linux file into multiple files?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I want to split a file into multiple files. My input is

```
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
$
Report : XYZ    Page: 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report  
$
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

The output should be:

File 1

```
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

File 2

```
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
$

Report : XYZ    Page: 2
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report  
$
```

File 3

```
Report : XYZ    Page: 1
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
   End of Report
$
```

I have tried

```
awk '{print $0 "Report :"> "/tmp/File" NR}' RS="END OF" test.txt
```

and

referred [How can I split my file into multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777097/how-can-i-split-my-file-into-multiple-files/27810122#27810122)

used

```
awk '/^Report/{filename++} {f="File"filename; if(lf != f) {close(lf); lf=f}} {print > f}' test.txt
```

but I'm not getting appropriate output.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: is this fix format like report followed by 6 lines?

Comment: no. Report can be big as well but end of report is like "End of Report
$". See the end of report

Comment: what's wrong with above command? i think that should work..

Comment: Using First command it is not working. Using second command it will create 4 files for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk way

```
awk '{print >"File"(i+=/Page: 1[^1-9]*/)}' file
```

Comment: It is working for this scenario. But my page no. is like Page: 11 then?

Comment: It's working but now i have two space after Page: 1  then it's not working properly. Could you please help me

Comment: I have resolve it. put [ ]* before $. Thanks Jidder for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk -v i=1 '{print > "File"i; if(/End of Report/)i++}' InputFile
```

It will generate 1 extra file though, which i hope shouldn't be a problem.

without extra file:

```
awk -v i=1 '{print > "File"i; if(/End of Report/)i++} END{system("rm File"i)}' InputFile
```

**Explanation:**

The script will start forwarding each line to `File 1 (since i=1 set initially)`. After printing each `End of Report`, `i is incremented` so that from next line onwards, contents will be forwarded to `File2` and so on for the rest of the file contents. One `extra file` will be generated which will contain the file contents after the last `End of Report` line, which can be removed easily if it is a problem.

Comment: This will remove extra file too : awk -v i=1 '{print > "File"i; if(/End of Report/)i++} END{system("rm File"i)}' InputFile

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I modified it a bit

```
csplit input.txt '/Page: 1$/' '{*}'
```

Comment: When i run above command. It's giving output as 221. but it's not creating file. Did this command store output in any other place?

Comment: @Viru it split and create files according to the filter provided as you can see.